# Multiple installations of ghc-mod

Tags: haskell, cabal, haskell-stack, ghc-mod

I have noticed I have 3 sets of ghc-mod.exe, ghc-modi.exe etc on my computer. The first one I suspect was created with stack. It is in

> c:\users\myname\appdata\roaming\local\bin

The 2nd one I think was created with cabal and is in

> c:\users\myname\appdata\roaming\cabal\bin

and the 3rd one again I suspect was created with stack. It is in

> C:\stack_root\snapshots\48375d44\bin

. At the moment my PATH is pointing to all 3 however I have renamed ghc-modi.exe and ghc-mod.exe in 2 folders and left version 5.6.0.0 in ~\roaming\cabal\bin unchanged. The whole thing is somewhat confusing and I suspect unnecessary. Do I need all 3 versions? How can I clean it up?

Answer (score 0):

Cabal installs to ~\cabal\bin and stack installs to both ~\48375d44\bin and ~\local\bin.